# Opposite of class loaders getSystemResourceAsStream

Tags: java

I have a template file on my class path, I want to read it change the appropriate values write to temp file than back to the template file and revert changes with same process before I end my programs execution.

How can I open stream for writing to the same resource I just read?

Looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

can't find my way around this.

This is my Inputstream :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + TEMPLATE_FILENAME);
```

How can I get output stream to same file?

or is it impossible to alter it in runtime? jar file itself?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the myClassLoader.getResource method and open a FileOutputStream with the returned URL:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29

M.